# What is the name for the wall behind the suspect in a mug shot?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

[image]

It's the wall that a suspect stands in front of when a mug shot is taken. I don't know what to call it so it's hard for me to find information about the wall itself.

Comment: Small point, Native English speakers will say "I don't know **what** to call" rather than '**how** to call'. It may help you in future internet searches if you phrase questions 'What do you call xxx?' or 'what is xxx called?' rather than using 'how'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn’t really have a particular name. It’s just a wall with height markings in feet on it.  However, sometimes people do refer to it as a [“police lineup wall”](http://www.policeone.com/communications/articles/1876141-Dallas-police-pioneering-new-photo-lineup-approach/). That because it’s the kind of thing they use in police lineups.

Notice the handcuffs in your image?  It’s making some sort of comment related to getting arrested or being in jail, or having one’s mugshot taken.  For example, from *The Usual Suspects*:

[image: usual suspects line-up]

You see this sort of wall markings all the time now in convenience stores and other places liable to be robbed. That’s because that way the video conveniently takes a picture of the bandits with their height clearly documented.

That said, the standard police lineup technique [doesn’t work very well](http://www.policeone.com/communications/articles/1876141-Dallas-police-pioneering-new-photo-lineup-approach/), and some jurisdictions have switched to sounder methods.  But the markings left on pillars next to checkout counters for video cameras to snap pictures of still have their own uses.

Comment: "You see this sort of wall markings all the time now in convenience stores": Yikes! Really?

Comment: Oh wow, I've noticed them in bank lobbies but didn't know that's what they were used for!

Comment: @sacohe: Did you think they were put there so that customers could measure their kids? :^) As for its name, one could call it a "height indicator". (The thin strips along convenience store door jambs are marketed under the name "height indicator tape".)

Comment: @J.R. That's what I used it for when I was a kid! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have seen "mug-shot wall," "mugshot wall," and also "[Rogue's Gallery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogues_gallery)" for something with a little flavor that describes the whole scene--wall and lineup. Rogue's Gallery could also refer to a collection of individual mug shot photos, so the usage would have to reflect that you are describing the criminal lineup.

Answer (score 1):

Its actually called a latitudinal height marker (LHM for short). The technique isn't always completely accurate, but the markings are still in use.

Comment: can you provide a source?